# Shinydahsboardplus: how to add box without a title?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

after recent update of `ShinydasboardPlus` (to 2.0) I can't manage to make `box` with no header and and no space for header.

I tried `title = NULL, headerBorder = FALSE` and still have this space. How to get rid of that? I want a box ONLY with content, no header, no space for header.
[image]

Thanks!

Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  title = "Box API",
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(
      title = NULL,
      headerBorder = FALSE,
      "Box body")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: sure! sorry for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `css` to not display the header. Something like this:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  title = "Box API",
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(
      id = 'foo',  # use an id to only select this box
      title = NULL,
      headerBorder = FALSE,
      "Box body"
    ),
    tags$head(tags$style('#foo .box-header{ display: none}'))  # target the box header of foo
  )
)
```