# Delete title section from shinydashboard box

Tags: r, shinydashboard

How can someone delete the `title` section in `shiny` box? Or reduce its height to `0`? No I dont want it `NULL` or `=""`

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(width=12)),
    fluidRow(
      box(title="something"),
      box())
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: no I mean the title of the boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this question, you can refer to this solution from another post answered by 'bobbel`:

[solution found on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66688910/shinydahsboardplus-how-to-add-box-without-a-title)

The `css' solution provided works for me.